# Run npm install --production on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, npm, openshift

When I push my code to OpenShift, it looks like it's installing my `devDependencies` which takes **forever**. I would really love to set it up so it will only install the `dependencies` (by running with the `--production` flag). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can tell npm to install using the `--production` flag by setting the `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` environment variable to "`true`".

Here is an example that should work for existing applications:

```
rhc env set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION="true"
```

Or, you can set this variable as a part of your initial app-create step:

```
rhc app create myapplication nodejs-0.10 NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION="true"
```

Comment: It is indicated in Openshift documentation : https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-j.s-environment-variables.html.
And moreover, it works!

Comment: With the options form of the command it's `rhc app create -a myapplication -t nodejs-0.10 --env NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION="true"`.

Answer (score 3):

Found a way to specify it in source instead of during app creation.
The benefit (for me) over an env var is that it applies to all ways to launch the app, including a "Launch on OpenShift" button.

Create an `.openshift/action_hooks/pre_build` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This makes npm not install devDependencies.
echo 'Enabling npm production'
echo 'production = true' >> $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/.npmrc
```

That's it!  I've tested and it does affect npm for this build, and the .npmrc disappears if you remove this hook in the future.

(Obviously I could also achieve this by simply adding an `.npmrc` to my repo, but do *not* want to affect people checking out the source and running `npm install`, only how it works on OpenShift.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the only solution is to update the cartridge itself.  The npm install command is located in the cartridge's bin/control folder.  Meanwhile, it's been fixed in the [originating github repo at wshearn/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs](https://github.com/wshearn/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs) so you can just install from github rather than using the Quickstart.

Comment: Thanks for the tip John. I see in the github repo where that command happens. Unfortunately, I installed using the quickstart and there's no bin/control file. You don't happen to know where I could make the change in the quickstart do you?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the official repo.  It seems the code currently used on RHcloud.com is https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs; it does [try to set NODE_ENV=production](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/commit/97124748e41d01ace67df931908755f84ecfdbae) but I'm seeing devDependencies installed nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a `.npmrc` file where the `node_modules` folder is located.
2. Open it with your `text-editor` and add this to it:

   `production = true`

P.S. no semicolons or any other characters

This will ensure that `devDependencies` are not installed on the `OPENSHIFT` server