# Application gets slow when I change server.js file Openshift

Tags: node.js, performance, http, response, openshift

I created a node app in openshift, I connected through SSH, and I was able to push my code and I could change the server.js code for a simple hello world.

**Server.js**

```
#!/bin/env node
 var http = require('http');
 var serverIp = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
 var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
 //creating server
 var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
      res.writeHead('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
      res.end('Simple example!!');
 });
 //listening
 server.listen(port, serverIp, function() {
     console.log('Server started on port ' + port + ' IP: ' + serverIp);
 });
```

When push this new code, I'm not getting any errors.
And this is the **package.json** file

```
{ "name": "Hello_world",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Hello world",
"engines": {
      "node": ">= 0.6.0",
      "npm": ">= 1.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"bundleDependencies": [],
"private": true,
"scripts": {
   "start" : "node server.js"
},
"main": "server.js"
}
```

When I do this, the application gets very very slow (like 2/3 minutes of waiting), here's the link.
[http://avalecia-minisis.rhcloud.com/]enter code here[1](http://avalecia-minisis.rhcloud.com/)
But when I change the code for the original, everything's fine... :/

I don't see where the issue could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deploying to OpenShift, your application's build process can be [optimized (or tuned) in a variety of ways](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/10-reasons-openshift-is-the-best-place-to-host-your-nodejs-app#build).

If you'd like to minimize downtime between deploys, you can try enabling [the `hot_deploy` feature](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/OpenShift/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-OpenShift-User_Guide-Hot_Deploying_Applications.html):

```
mkdir .openshift ; mkdir .openshift/markers ; touch .openshift/markers/hot_deploy
git add .openshift/markers/hot_deploy
git commit -m "enabling the hot_deploy marker to minimize downtime on OpenShift"
git push
```

[Checking in your `node_modules` folder](http://www.futurealoof.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html) can also have a major impact on build time.

Turning on [`NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724133/run-npm-install-production-on-openshift/23749201#23749201) is another approach that may help (see : [Run npm install --production on OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724133/run-npm-install-production-on-openshift/23749201#23749201))